# How to load a value from a div in a React component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to dynamically set a value within my `cart` constructor. My `cart` variable has price, item. and size values. I want to assign a value to `item` dynamically on what item has been clicked. This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addCart } from '../../actions';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
//import { Cart } from './webcart';


import CamoHat from './camodye.jpeg';
import TonyTape from './TonyTape.png';
import RegularHat from './regularhat.jpg';
import JaguarShirt from './JAGUARLOGO.png';
import SeltzShirt from './seltzshirt.jpg';
import NocHoodie from './NOCNOCHOODIE.png';

export class WebShop extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: 'medium', cartData: {} };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.change = this.change.bind(this);
        this.goProductPage = this.goProductPage.bind(this);
        this.goProductPage2 = this.goProductPage2.bind(this);
        this.goProductPage3 = this.goProductPage3.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        let cart = {price:0,item:"userselection",size:this.state.value};
        this.props.onCartAdd(cart);
        this.itemSelection(cart);
    } 

    change(e){
        this.setState({value: e.target.value})
    }

    itemSelection(cart){
        let userItem = cart;
        let userSelection = cart
        if (userItem == "shirt1") {
           let itemPrice = 20.00;
        }
    }
    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='Webshop' id='Webshop'>
                <ul id="Productlist">
                    <div className='Product'>
                      <img src={CamoHat} onClick={this.goProductPage}></img>
                      <div id='infoname'>NOC NOC HAT (CAMO)</div>
                      <div id='infoprice'>40.00</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='Product'>
                      <img src={JaguarShirt} onClick={this.goProductPage2}></img>
                      <div id='infoname'>JAGUAR PYRAMIDS T-SHIRT</div>
                      <div id='infoprice'>25.00</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='Product'>
                      <img src={SeltzShirt} onClick={this.goProductPage3}></img>
                      <div id='infoname'>JAGUAR PYRAMIDS T-SHIRT</div>
                      <div id='infoprice'>25.00</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='Product'>
                      <img src={NocHoodie} onClick={this.goProductPage}></img>
                      <div id='infoname'>JAGUAR PYRAMIDS T-SHIRT</div>
                      <div id='infoprice'>25.00</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='Product'>  
                      <img src={RegularHat}></img>
                      <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="addit">Add to cart</button>
                      <select id="size" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                        <option value="large">Large</option>
                        <option value="x-large">X-large</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className='Product'>  
                      <img src={TonyTape}></img>
                      <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="addit">Add to cart</button>
                      <select id="size" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                        <option value="large">Large</option>
                        <option value="x-large">X-large</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

...

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(WebShop);
```

I want to assign the `item` value in `cart` using the description of the item within the item `div id=infoname` (the text itself) for ex: `NOC NOC Hat`. How can I do this within my function? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Unclear what is being asked here. Why is `cart` not a property of the component's `state`? What does the `itemSelection` method do? It assigns values to some variables but does nothing with them.

Comment: `Cart` could be in state I guess, I just wrote it that way and it works.. I have not finished writing the `itemSelection` method because here is where I need to get the value from the div. What I want is to get the item name when add to cart is used, assigning that name to the `item` value in `cart`. @dogui

Comment: 1) Don't use the same `id` more than once. 2) Since each `div` represents a product, why not [use `data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)? They can have spaces in them unlike `id` attributes.

Comment: If you need more help you should consider asking a new question and providing a minimal, complete, verifiable example using a service like CodeSandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way to do what you want to do is to use refs : 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Quote from the official doc :

> The ref attribute takes a callback function, and the callback will be
>   executed immediately after the component is mounted or unmounted.
>
> When the ref attribute is used on an HTML element, the ref callback
>   receives the underlying DOM element as its argument

I have removed some lines from your code so that it compiles for me.
Here it is : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/314N8jxG9

Look at line 22 and 46. (check the console.log output)

The ref attributes receives a callback that can access the div element, thus it innerHTML value.

This is not the best way to do it but this will fix your issue.

---

Now the best is to use props.

Please, refactor your code by first extracting your products items into ProductIem this way :

```
  const ProductItdem = ({description, price})=>{
        return (
              <div className='Product'>
                          <div id='infoname'   >{description}</div>
                          <div id='infoprice'>{price}</div>
                        </div>
        );
    }
```

You can even compose them in a ProductList Component.
Then you will pass props from you WebShop container component to the dumm components.

Try it and let us know your questions.

Comment: I was going with using refs before seeing your answer. But with your example I managed to get what I wanted this way. Why wouldn't this be the best way to do it?